# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element WTH?

Tags: java, xml

Could some PLEASE tell me where and how I fix this stupid namespace issue?!  It should not be this hard to parse XML!

```
JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"getRecordsResponse") Expected elements are: http://www.example.com/task}getRecords
```

Here is the annotated class generated by JAXB2 and Maven.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "getRecordsResult"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getRecordsResponse")
public class GetRecordsResponse {
```

How do I tell JAXB2 to add the correct namespace?

Comment: I mean, where the heck do i say "Hey Mr Jaxb2Marshaller!!  My silly provide didn't define a name space?! Use this one and pretend it's the correct one!"

Comment: You can start by posting the JAXB-annotated classes you're working with and what your webservice provider is expecting in the soap payload vs what you're sending